# Wget converting links differently on different environments

Tags: wget

I set up a Ruby script to download and archive some pages of a website using Wget. We have a dockerized Rails application and we use Elastic Beanstalk to manage testing environments. The issue is that I have a different outcome in my test environment than in all the other environments, even if the Wget version is the same (1.18).

This is the command

```
docker exec -it xxxxxxxx sh -c 'wget -H -E -p -k -N --no-cookies --header "Cookie: myCookie=123" --timeout=2000 --restrict-file-names=windows --no-check-certificate -e robots=off "http://path.to/resource"'
```

where

```
-H (--span-hosts), -E (--adjust-extension), -p (--page-requisites), -k (--convert-links), -N (--timestamping)
```

and this is how links to stylesheets are correctly converted into relative, after downloading the CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../../assets/ss-standard-931774a45f6c2e79b3fb8ac6ce1eca4e4a9208b3c80a1c289f36b317b830db6b.css" />
```

but on that specific test environment, a `.html` is appended

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="../../assets/ss-standard-931774a45f6c2e79b3fb8ac6ce1eca4e4a9208b3c80a1c289f36b317b830db6b.css.html" />
```

couldn't find anything helpful so far... Any idea?

Comment: try remove --adjust-extension  : If a file of type ‘application/xhtml+xml’ or ‘text/html’ is downloaded and the URL does not end with the regexp ‘\.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?’, this option will cause the suffix ‘.html’ to be appended to the local filename.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'll go for that, adjusting the HTML file after download (since without that option, it won't have the .html extension). The strange things are that:
1 - Even with -E, assets file names are correct, .html is being added only to the links to them.
2 - This is happening only in one specific environment.